# How do I exit the nl command in CentOS?

Tags: command-line, command, centos

I'm really a noob in the CLI, so please help me. I accidentally entered nl in CentOS and now I'm stuck in this list. How do I exit nl?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't have figured this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ctrl-C can usually be used to kill terminal commands in linux.

EDIT:
Ctrl-D should be used to terminate nl correctly. Ctrl-C is just a general way to kill applications.

Comment: Ctrl-D is nicer as that just closes the input file descriptor making nl exit cleanly. Ctrl-C kills the process with SIGINT.

Comment: That is true. I don't have much experience with nl so I was just showing a quick way to kill processes. I will edit my answer.